# Spring JPA вернуть несколько столбцов как список объектов

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Я пишу проект на Spring Data JPA. У меня есть таблица, в которой примерно десять полей:

```
create table test (
  a varchar(255),
  b varchar(255),
  c varchar(255),
  date timestamp,
  type varchar(255),
  d varchar(255));
```

Из этих полей мне надо извлечь только два поля `date` и `type`, и при этом запрос должен вернуть список объектов, в которых инкапсулированы эти два поля. Даты в результате не должны повторяться.

Это можно сделать при помощи JPA? А при помощи JdbcTemplate?

Comment: Можно и в том и другом случае, поля не обязательно мапить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<Test, Long> {
  @Query("select t.date, t.type  from Test t")
  List<Object[]> searchCustom();
}
```

Или же можно создавать java-объекты прямо  в запросе:

```
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<Test, Long> {
  @Query("select new example.TestWrapper(t.date, t.type)  from Test t")
  List<Object[]> searchCustom();
}
```

+

```
package example;

public class TestWrapper{

  private Timestamp date;
  private String type;

  public TestWrapper(){}

  public TestWrapper(String date,String type){
      this.date=date;
      this.type=type;
  }
  //..... get + set
}
```